# jquery elementby class and set name

Tags: jquery

can some one help me with code to get element by classname and also change the name

currently ive tried

```
$('selected').attr("name", 'blah blah');
```

and also

```
$('.selected').attr("name", 'blah blah');
```

noneof these work
thanks

Comment: Try pasting your code in your question instead of a comment line, or if there is too much paste it into a bin like http://jsbin.com/

Answer (score 2):

- `$('.classname')` should work for finding your elements by class name (try by checking `.length`)
- `.attr("name", "foo")` should definitely work.

Care to share some HTML code and matching JavaScript?

EDIT:

Given your sample code, and assuming you're using ASP.NET MVC's `Html` helper.

1. You may be passing a bad name to `HtmlHelper.DropDownList`, there's a period in it ("`cat.parent_id`")
2. I'm not sure `HtmlHelper.DropDownList` supports the way you're trying to pass a class to each `<option>` element (but you can verify by viewing the page's source).

If what you're trying to do is change the text in the currently-selected option, and given:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList('my_ddlist', someEnumerable); %>
```

You can try to use jQuery's "`:selected`" pseudo-selector instead, and change the option text with `.text()`:

```
$('select#my_ddlist option:selected').text("foo");
```

If you're trying to do something else, can you explain what?

Comment: thats the html


            <tr><td> <%=Html.Label("Category")%></td><td>
           <%= Html.DropDownList("cat.parent_id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData.Model.AllCategoriesList, "-please select item-", new { className = "unselected" })%>
          </td>

Comment: i cant paste the script not enough characters sorry

Comment: tom, you can edit your original question and add the code. So you are trying to get at a `<select>` element? It's not clear based on the question.